# scheduling events in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

I have 4 python scripts that I've mostly run from command-line. I've been trying to schedule them, but so far I haven't found a good way to do this. I have some requirements on how this all should work.

My scripts and what they do:

**script number 1**; Scans big number of records from database and does some processing.

**script number 2**; Does more processing, ***should run only after script number 1 is finished***

**scripts number 3&4**; these scripts are not related to 1 or 2, but they should be run hourly.

Any recommendations what would the best approach for scheduling these scripts in Python?

Comment: What is the OS you are using?

Comment: [`apscheduler`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Is scheduling the scripts in python a hard requirement? Normally one would use something like cron or systemd to schedule hourly running (assuming linux).

Comment: Here is the link which you can refer - https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab/

Comment: If you're using a linux-like OS, don't overcomplicate yourself and just go with `cron` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), and create independent schedules. 

The first schedule will run: `python /path/to/script1.py && python /path/to/scrip2.py`. 
 
The second schedule should run hourly (cron expression `0 * * * *`) and should run `python /path/to/scrip3.py`. 
 
Finally, the 3rd schedule should be also scheduled hourly (cron expression `0 * * * *`) and should run `python /path/to/scrip4.py`

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the required job needs to schedule.
For scheduling jobs, It's good to use CI tools like Jenkins.

1. make a job for script 1 and 2 and run script 2 after completing script 1.
2. make two jobs separately for script 3 & 4 that running every hour.

Answer (score 0):

There is the good framework for scheduling python (and not only python!) scripts!
Take a look: https://github.com/spotify/luigi
It already has 13k stars at github, used in prod at many companies, have a lot of tutorials. It is developed and supported by spotify, so it is actively updated. And, of course, open source :)

Use can install it easily through PyPi next way:

```
pip install luigi
```

It even has web-GUI if you prefer that.
I really recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with Python, there's apscheduler.
Instead of running the scripts separately, import them and run their functions instead.

Example:

```
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

# your script 1 main function (should be imported instead of creating here)
def my_script1():
    pass

# your script 2 main function (should be imported instead of creating here)
def my_script2():
    pass


# This exists so 
def my_script_runner():
    my_script1()
    my_script2()

# your script 3 main function (should be imported instead of creating here)
def my_script3(id=None):
    print(id)

job_kwargs = {
    'id': 1
}

# Hourly job

scheduler.add_job(my_script_runner, 'interval', [], None, name='myscripts1and2', seconds=7200)

scheduler.add_job(fn, 'interval', [], job_kwargs, name='myscript3', seconds=3600)
scheduler.start()


# Main executer loop
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    scheduler.shutdown()
```